# My value violates not-null constraint when its not null

Tags: python, django, django-models

I encountered an exception while saving the model

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "city" of relation "price_shop" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (<id>, <name>, <address>, <ratings>, <owner__id>, <contacts>, <categories>, null, <city>).`

I don't know what is null means, maybe this counted as city

My models.py file:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class City(models.Model):
    readonly_fields = ('lower_name',)
    exclude = ('name_lower ',)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name_lower = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_lower = self.name.lower()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Shop(models.Model):
    readonly_fields = ('ratings',)
    exclude = ('ratings ',)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ratings = models.FloatField(default=0.0, editable=False)
    contacts = models.JSONField(default=dict, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.JSONField(default=dict, null=True, blank=True)

    city = models.ForeignKey(City, models.PROTECT, to_field='name', null=True, blank=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    readonly_fields = ('name_lower',)
    exclude = ('name_lower ',)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name_lower = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    sale = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static', null=True, blank=True)
    markdown = models.TextField(null=True, default="Магазин не оставил описания")
    tags = models.JSONField()

    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_lower = self.name.lower()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.shop.name}: {self.name}"


class Review(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=tuple((i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 6)))

    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

My form in admin page is looking like this:
[image]

I want the model to be preserved successfully.
I tried to remove the review model, believing that the many-to-one relationship created this null